# How much of the roof of a sukkah must be open?

Tags: sukkah

Yesterday, during lunchtime in a sukkah with generous schach, l got into a discussion on the minimum and maximum fraction of the area of the roof of a sukkah that must be sufficiently open that you can see the sky, and how concentrated that fraction must be.  Are there any halachot on that?

Comment: there is no obligation to see the sky. The Mishnah in the second perek says you do not need to see the stars, and the gemara says that according to Beis Hillel, you do not even need to be able to see the sun.

Comment: Why do you think you must see the sky?

Comment: Great question: I am assuming that when you wrote "the sky" you mean the stars. The chaye adam[ klal 146][1] states that "ולכתחלה יהיה הסיכוך קל כדי שיראו ממנו הכוכבים גדולים הנראים בלילה"

For those who do not read Hebrew well (I usually get comments if I just put in Hebrew)...Lichatchila, the schach should be thin enough to see large stars at night" 

so there is definitely a source why one would want to see the sky because they'd want to see the stars at night.

As far as the "fraction" or shiurim on how much, I haven't seen anything on that.